# Creating a hyperlink for a cell found by FIND function

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote VBA code to search for a word in "Sheet1". The list of words are in "Sheet2". The results are published in "Sheet3" along with the word and all the cell addresses of the word found in "Sheet1".

The cell addresses are published as "$B$26" for example. I want this to be a hyperlink to cell B26 of Sheet1.

I used the below code.

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate

'Record the address of the data, in the current workbook.

     With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
        .Value = "Address of variable:"
        .Offset(0, -1).Value = "Variable Name"
        .Offset(0, -2).Value = "No of usages"
        .Offset(i, 0).Value = GCell.Address
        .Offset(i, -1).Value = Txt
        .Columns.AutoFit
        .Offset(i, 1).Columns.AutoFit

If GCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Sheets("Sheet3").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(i,0), _
         Address:="", _
         SubAddress:="'" & Sheets("Sheet1").Name & "'!" & GCell.Address, TextToDisplay:="Click"
```

I get

> Run time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

on the above line. `GCell` is the range where the word is found.

Comment: *"But I get a error on the above line"* Without telling **which** error this information is pretty useless. Please also include the relevant code part (one line is not enough). Did you check `GCell` for `Nothing` after using `Find`?

Comment: Sorry about that. Edited now. Yes I check GCell for Nothing after using FIND.

Comment: Yes it did work! Thanks a lot.. was checking every other thing!! Thank you PEH..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is `.Cells(i,0)`.

Row/Column numbering starts with `1` not `0` so the column `0` does not exist, therefore you get an error. Also ensure that `i` is `>0`.

---

And I highly recommend to avoid using `.Activate` and `ActiveSheet` instead reference your worksheets by their name. You might benefit from reading 
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

This …

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("D2")
```

can be written as …

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D2")
```

Comment: Yes it did work! Thanks a lot.. was checking every other thing!! Thank you PEH! And yes I eliminated the use of '.Activate' as well. Thanks!!! :)